# django.utils.timezone.activate effect

Tags: django, timezone

I have a question concerning `django.utils.timezone` package.

I am at UTC+7 timezone. Thus, if it is 16:00 local time,
`timezone.now()` returns 9:00. That is just fine.

However when I do the following:

```
current_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')  # UTC + 4
timezone.activate(current_tz)
```

I expect `timezone.now()` to return 12:00 at 16:00 localtime, but the output remains the same "9:00".

Does timezone.activate() affects on anything at all?

Answer (score 12):

`timezone.now()` explicitly returns UTC time.

After timezone.activate, then `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())` returns the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me, and I stumbled on this question when trying to find out how to change the timezone in the admin view in the change list.
Here is my full example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils import timezone

from audience.models import ClientTrending

TRENDING_TZ = 'Canada/Eastern'


class ClientTrendingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Admin Interface configuration for model"""

    def get_changelist_instance(self, request):
        timezone.activate(TRENDING_TZ)
        return super().get_changelist_instance(request)



admin.site.register(ClientTrending, ClientTrendingAdmin)
```

You can also pass the timezone string name value as I am using above.